# What does this code mean? how does the count increase?

Tags: java

I am new to Java so I don't really understand this yet, I just want to know how does this code work and how the count increase. Why is there a loop inside a loop?
(This is not my own code it is something i am studying.)

```java
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    int n = r.nextInt(3);
    Gridbox[i][j] = n;
    if (n == 0)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Java naming conventions have methods and variables start with a lower case letter (gridBox).

Answer (score 0):

`r.nextInt(3)` results in a uniform random number between 0 (inclusive) and 3 (exclusive). Why? Because the [docs say so](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html); javadoc is a great place to start when trying to figure out what things do.

In other words, 33% of the time that returns 0, 33% of the time it returns 1, and 33% of the time it returns 2, randomly determined.

In other words, 33% of the time (on average), n would be 0, and count would be increased.

All this code does is loop 5 times (first 'for'), and per outer loop, loop 5 times (for a total of 5*5 = 25 times a random number is generated).

Gridbox is some sort of 5 by 5 array; the randomly generated number is placed in this grid, and count is incremented 33% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

The count increases here, by one each time this line is executed:

```java
count++;
```

Look up the increment operator `++` to understand.

There is loop inside a loop, a socalled pair of nested loops, in order to cover all possible combinations of possible `i`s and `j`s, i.e. to cover all of the 2D range.

If you want to learn a programming language I recommend to first read a book and maybe follow tutorials. Reading existing code is for later, though not a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I added a comment to every line of code; and tried to explain here.

You're creating a `gridbox` of size ***i** x **j***. In your code's case you are hardcoding **i** and **j** to  a size of 5(using the for loops both sized 5)

`r.nextInt(3)` results in a uniform random number between 0 (inclusive) and 3 (exclusive). So you are assigning each value inside the gridbox a random value between 0 and 3.

Whenever you do the assignment, if the value is 0 increment the count.

```java
//random class that allows generation of random values
Random r = new Random();
//for loop of size 5, start at 0 and go through it 5 times. **i** is the first param of gridbox
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

//for loop of size 5, start at 0 and go through it 5 times. **j** is the second param of Gridbox
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    // assign random integer value between 0 and 3 to field n. 
    int n = r.nextInt(3);
    // push n into GridBox.  this might be a typo. In java Capital indicates its a class not a instance of the class
    Gridbox[i][j] = n;
    // if **n  is equal 0 increment count. 
    if (n == 0)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

I imagine you need to do a instantiation

```java
    //this needs to be properly instantiated, to right size. 
    Gridbox gridbox = new Gridbox();
    gridbox[i][j] = n
```